# 15 line Rust program, which writes the numbers 1 to N to a file

Tags: performance, rust

I have this simple Rust program, which creates a file called `numbers.txt` and writes the numbers 1 to N (N is here 10000000) to it, separated with newlines:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

const N: i32 = 1e7 as i32;

fn main() {
    let mut data = String::new();

    for i in 1..=N  {
        data.push_str(&format!("{0}\n", i));
    }

    let mut f = File::create("numbers.txt").expect("Unable to create file");
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

I've been running and timing the program with:

```
$ time cargo run --release
```

`numbers.txt` after running:

```
1
2
3
4
...
9999999
10000000
```

I've timed the execution of the program, and it takes around 4.8 seconds to run on my machine. I tried timing just the string building, by commenting out the last two lines, and the time taken stayed pretty much the same. We can conclude that the bottleneck is the `data` string building and not writing to the file.

**How could I make building `data` faster? Should I use something else than a `String`?**

Comment: You've run the test in debug mode, don't you? You must benchmark it in release mode.

Comment: No, I used `cargo run --release` to run the code. And actually `$ time cargo run --release`, when I needed to see the execution time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I improved the performances (and simplicity) like this:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io::BufWriter;

const N: i32 = 1e7 as i32;

fn main() {
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create("numbers.txt").expect("Unable to create file"));
    for i in 1..=N  {
        write!(f, "{0}\n", i);
    }

}
```

I just don't store the strings in a gigantic buffer but asks the BufWriter to manage the buffering. As a side effect, it's now possible to write bigger files without holding too much RAM.

Comment: Nice! This cut the runtime on my system from 4.8s to 1.4s!

Answer (score 0):

This cuts the runtime by about a third (4.8s -> 3.2s):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

const N: i32 = 1e7 as i32;

fn main() {
    let data = (1..=N)
        .map(|n| n.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join("\n");

    let mut f = File::create("numbers.txt").expect("Unable to create file");
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

Comment: I'd like to see your benchmark: because that code is actually slower in the playground: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=d0553c164ed0a6fc0db9b3b61aa2c012

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Sure! I repeated this multiple times and always got practically identical results: https://i.imgur.com/gJq5Ugx.png

Answer (score 0):

How about some threads?

```
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

const N: i32 = 1e7 as i32;

fn main() {
    let mut output = File::create("numbers.txt").unwrap();

    let data: Vec<String> = (1..=N)
        .into_par_iter()
        .fold(String::new, |mut lhs, rhs| {
            use std::fmt::Write;
            write!(&mut lhs, "{}\n", rhs).unwrap();
            lhs
        })
        .collect();

    for part in data {
        output.write_all(&part.into_bytes()).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you benchmark this compared to my original or @DenysSéguret's answer?

Comment: @ruohola, I did. On my machine mine is much faster. Of course, threads are involved so its going to be very different machine to machine.

Comment: Ok, would this be possible to be written without the `rayon` external dependency.

Comment: @ruohola, you could, of course, write threading code directly using the stdlib instead of using rayon, but why would you want to?